# Loading CSS bootstrap-4 theme for sweet-alert2

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, sweetalert2

I use SweetAlert2 for my project. I use VueJS and vue-cli-service with webpack.

As I wanted to use the boostrap-4 theme, I followed the instructions :

```
npm i npm install @sweetalert2/theme-bootstrap-4
```

And I included this css in the index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@sweetalert2/themes/bootstrap-4/bootstrap-4.css">
```

But it only results in a 404 error, and of course, the theme is not showing. I don't seem to understand how it is supposed to work and what is wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I am not using VueJS in my project but I had a similar issue and thought I'd share my solution for others finding this question.

1. Make sure you are importing Swal from `sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js` and not just from `sweetalert` as the latter will override all the styles. [Docs here](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2-themes#usage).
2. The docs then say you should be able to use SASS with `@import 'sweetalert2/themes/dark/dark.scss';` or CSS using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="@sweetalert2/themes/bootstrap-4/bootstrap-4.css">`. I am not using SASS and the CSS did not work for me. Instead I just linked the style sheet from 'jsdelivr' with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@sweetalert2/theme-bootstrap-4@5.0.10/bootstrap-4.css"`.

If you don't want to use 'jsdelivr' you could copy/link the stylesheet from `node_modules\@sweetalert2\theme-bootstrap-4\bootstrap-4.min.css`

Answer (score 0):

As per the [README of @sweetalert2/theme-bootstrap-4](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2-themes/tree/master/bootstrap-4) you need to use

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@sweetalert2/theme-bootstrap-4/bootstrap-4.css">
```

Comment: No, it's useless, still a 404.